# How to Access a NAS outside your home network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, nas

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question but here goes.

I recently purchased a Synology NAS DS918+ and have a few beginner questions to ask. I have 2 people that would like to assess the NAS (One is at a local university, the other is on the other side of the country).

I have 2 questions id like to ask.

1) What is the "best practice" way to allow these 2 people to connect to the NAS?

2) Would it help to install a VPN on the router? or do they have to log in to a VPN on their side giving the illusion that they are on my home network in order to access it?

Thanks for any help or advice in advance.

**Update: I was given this information on the 'networkengineering' stackexchange.**

Basically, there are two different approaches:

1) Given the NAS is hardenend and isn't affected by hacking, you could map/open the required port/s on the firewall. Without hardening, setting up access to the NAS doesn't only endanger the NAS and its data but also the entire network.

2) Provide transparent access through a VPN tunnel. VPN allows remote access without exposing your network devices to hacking from the Internet. You might want to set up VPN rules to restrict remote users to the devices in question.

**My Response**

Awesome! thanks for your response! An additional question. Are we talking about the end user VPN'ing into my network? The reason I'm asking is the 2 end user have 0 technical experience so I want to make the process as simple and foolproof for them - given this info which of the 2 options would you recommend? and could you be so kind to point me to a guide to enact such a setup?

Comment: "Given the NAS is hardened and isn't affected by hacking" - It might be hardened but it would still affected by hacking.

Comment: You've got some experience with the SE network, and the same Q&A structure applies here.  The knowledge base relies on questions being just a single question and answers being the solutions to it.  You've got some "forum stuff" going on--using one post as a thread, with question, answer, and new questions.  It's likely to be closed as unclear or too broad as-is.  Can you rework this?  Ask clarifying questions as comments on the answer or a new question.  Split this into question and answer, or revise the question to incorporate the update.  But don't invalidate the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the end users have to VPN into your local network. Even though this avoids to expose the NAS to the outer world, the VPN (if not properly set) will expose not only the NAS but **all of your local network** to the people connecting to it.

Apart from this aspect, you need to consider that the VPN can be estabilished either from the user's pc or can be a stable VPN connection estabilished at router level.

In the first scenario, you can setup in Windows/Ubuntu/OSX a VPN account (for instance a PPTP) such that the user decides when to connect to the VPN. Once connected, the NAS will be accessible through its private (or LAN) ip address.

In the second scenario, you would need to set up a proper router to estabilish a VPN connection with a remote party. This solution, even though is a transparent approach, will expose the VPN connection to all of the users connected to that router. If you are managing good network devices and you put in place a proper configuration, you can avoid this to happen and decide to expose the VPN connection only to a set of selected users.

Comment: Awesome.

I think option 2 is the best solution for all parties involved. Is the process router specific? or generic across pretty much all routers?

If not generic, is there a best router to purchase to mitigate the chances of this going sideways?

And when you say 'expose the VPN connection only to a set of selected users' are you saying that i can set only certian IP address to access certain devices on the network?

Comment: @XmalevolentX personally I would suggest you to make use of Mikrotik devices that are quite advanced and at the same time you can get them for reasonable prices. With these devices you can for instance set up PPTP or IPSec VPNs up to your preference. Yes, you can set up the device ini order to expose only certain devices on the network through the VPN. Of course this will require from your side some configuration work